# SQL Server performs index scan when specifying columns rather than when using the * operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to optimize a query where we find the most recent records in a large table using a simple `SELECT MAX(Timestamp) ... GROUP BY Id` and I've narrowed down the query to some behaviour I don't quite understand...

When I run the below query everything works as I'd expect...

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON

DECLARE @__dataSourceId nvarchar(12) = N'test'

SELECT [b0].*
FROM 
    (SELECT [b].[BondId]
     FROM [BondPrices] AS [b]
     WHERE [b].[DataSourceId] = @__dataSourceId 
       AND ([b].[BenchmarkBondId] = 'a' OR 
            [b].[BenchmarkBondId] = 'b'  OR 
            [b].[BenchmarkBondId] = 'c')
     GROUP BY [b].[BondId]) AS [t]
INNER JOIN 
    [BondPrices] AS [b0] ON [t].[BondId] = [b0].[BondId]


-- Results (232 records returned):
-- Table 'BondPrices'. Scan count 39, logical reads 238
```

[image: Fast query]

However...

If I change the above code from `SELECT [b0].*` to just `SELECT [b0].[BondId]` the query execution plan changes from an **Index Seek** to and **Index Scan** which strikes me as odd, and seems to have a detrimental impact on performance.

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON

DECLARE @__dataSourceId nvarchar(12) = N'test'

SELECT 
    [b0].[BondId] -- this is the only change
FROM
    (SELECT [b].[BondId]
     FROM [BondPrices] AS [b]
     WHERE [b].[DataSourceId] = @__dataSourceId 
       AND ([b].[BenchmarkBondId] = 'a' OR 
            [b].[BenchmarkBondId] = 'b'  OR 
            [b].[BenchmarkBondId] = 'c')
     GROUP BY [b].[BondId]) AS [t]
INNER JOIN 
    [BondPrices] AS [b0] ON [t].[BondId] = [b0].[BondId]


-- Results (232 records returned):
-- Table 'BondPrices'. Scan count 6, logical reads 4396
```

[image: Slow query]

Is there a reason why selecting just a single (indexed) column would cause the query plan to change so drastically?

How could I ensure my query performs a Seek rather than a Scan in this instance?

**Edit**: as requested, the below are the indexes in question:

```
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_BondPrices] 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([BondId] ASC, [DataSourceId] ASC, [Timestamp] ASC)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_BondPrices_BondId_Timestamp] 
ON [dbo].[BondPrices] ([BondId] ASC, [Timestamp] ASC)
```

The non-clustered index is an attempt at forcing the join to perform an index seek although it would be more optimal if the query could use the clustered index.

**Edit**: also including the tooltip containing the warning.

[image: tooltip warning]

Comment: So I notice 2 things - join type changes to merge, with a decent increase on percentage. Second, now youre not using the clustered index, which to me tells me thats probably the issue. What are the two index definitions?

Comment: the accepted answer explains the reason why this is occurring. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/185837/any-reason-to-have-both-an-index-with-included-columns-and-one-without

Comment: Have you created Nonclustered Index on **BondPrices** table Covering all the columns ? That is the reason why it performs "Seek" for [b0].* and "Scan" for [b0].[BondId]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to comment, I've added index definitions as requested. Thanks @doug-coates, I'll read the article you posted now.

Comment: Your first query isn't doing one seek. It is doing 34 seeks as it is on the inside of a nested loops. SQL Server estimates that it will need to do nearly 5,000 seeks and costs a single full scan and a merge join as cheaper. (estimated operator cost of 4.3 vs 15.9) - so the issue is the overestimate of the number of rows that it thinks it will need to lookup. Do you get a more accurate estimate of number of seeks needed/different plan if you add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` so it can sniff the value of `@__dataSourceId`?

Comment: `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` unfortunately returns the same results

Comment: What is the yellow exclamation mark telling you on the root of the plan?

Comment: I'm not sure. There's no "warnings" in the dialog nor in the query plan XML generated doc. Is there another way to view warnings?

Comment: I'd expect to see it in a tooltip when mousing over the operator and definitely it will be somewhere in the plan XML as this is what is used to render the display. What is the datatype of  `DataSourceId` column? If it is `varchar` rather than `nvarchar` you will get an implicit cast which can make cardinality estimates less accurate

Comment: Updated the question to contain the tooltip. The plan XML only contains an empty `<Warnings />` node. I agree this is odd given the GUI is only rendering from the plan.

The DataSourceId column is an `nvarchar(12)`. Updated the variable to mirror this also, however, I get the same results.

Comment: Right - I guess the presence of the `Warnings` node is sufficient to trigger the drawing of the exclamation mark even though there is no useful text